# error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Tags: c++, class

I have this 2 separated class and i cant fix this compiler problem:

> In file included from classA.cpp:2:0:
>   classB.h:6:10: error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
>        std::string str;
>             ^
>
> In file included from classA.cpp:3:0:
>   classA.h:6:25: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
>        classB *ptr_b = new classB;

There is the classA.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

class classA {
private:
    classB *ptr_b = new classB;
public:
    classA();
};

#endif /* CLASSA_H */
```

classA.cpp:

```
#include "classB.h"
#include "classA.h"

classA::classA() {
}
```

classB.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

class classB {
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    classB();

};

#endif /* CLASSB_H */
```

classB.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "classB.h"

classB::classB() {
}
```

I apreciate all the help you can give. I don´t know how to fix this and I'm going crazy.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should `#include <string>` from classB.h. As it stands, <string> is included by classB.cpp but not classA.cpp (which also includes classB.h).

Comment: if i include <string> in classB.h i can delete on classB.cpp?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it from classB.cpp if it's in classB.h.

Comment: @BlackB0ltz you should keep it in classB.cpp as well if that file uses `std::string`, please don't depend on indirect includes as they are fragile. If you don't use string in classB.cpp feel free to remove it.

Comment: So, if i use the string in classB.cpp, I have to include <string> in classB.h and classB.cpp? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `#include <string>` in `classB.h`. Right now `classA.cpp` includes `classB.h` with no prior `#include <string>` anywhere, so the included reference to `std::string` in `classB.h` causes an error.

In general, if a name is used in a header `foo.h`, you should include the header `bar.h` that declares the name in `foo.h`, or forward-declare the name in `foo.h`. Otherwise everyone else who includes `foo.h` will need to remember to make sure `bar.h` gets included first.

Comment: Thanks for the help.